# Scipy | Stats: Iterate through variable selection (add or remove feature depending on AdjR2): Regression

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am working a project that investigates how well **nightly price** can be predicted on a airbnb dataset. My data has been fully preprocessed and I have selected features of interest.

**ultimately, looking for a paper with code as an example, provided you have any links available**

[image]

[image]

there is 24 columns in total, therefore 23 dependant and 1 independant variables `price`.

I want to add and remove variables from my model depending on how it affects the **Adj R2**, and only wish to keep the features of interest if it improves the Adj R2.

I aim to fullfill this task under a user defined function:

```
df=[]
predictors= [] #features
target=[]  # price
alpha=[]  

def variable_selection (df, predictors, target, alpha)
   return pred
```

thing is, i want to start with one variable regression models, then add another feature from `predictors`, then add the feature that leads to the largest increase in AdjR2. Then add the next and so fourth until the there is no variables left that increases AdjR2.

Thank you ever so much for getting this far. All the best to you

Comment: How big is the dataset? There are `sum([scipy.special.comb(23,i) for i in range(1,24)]) = 8_388_607.0` combinations of potential input matricies. A computer can (probably) come up with 8 million regressions faster than I can come up with a smart algorithm.

Comment: roughly 17,000 rows, 24 columns. I already appreciate this input. Im sat here like the monkey ive been trying to figure out a program for this. Needless to say there has been no progression. I can afford to drop a few columns but not many. possibly 5 at most if thats a limitation. Would just like to add a feature on a regression, iterating 1 by 1 until adj R2 reaches max potential for the given model

Comment: @DavidKaften Currently looking at the following documentation: If you have any advice from: https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html ,  on how to iterate through variables, it would be greatly appreciated